# Creo que el StringContent no está funcionando correctamente

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, windows-forms, asp.net-web-api

Bueno les doy un poco de contexto, estoy en una solucion WebAPI .NET con 3 proyectos:
Cine_Back (Biblioteca de Clases), CineFront (Aplicación de Windows Form) y CineWebAPI (ASP.NET Core Web API).
La cuestión es que tengo el NuGet NewtonSoft.Json, y lo estoy usando para serializar mi objeto Funcion que más adelante les dejo cómo está compuesto, el objeto se serializa bien, pero el problema es que a la hora de convertirlo en un StringContent para pasárselo a la API, el content queda sin valores, y se le termina pasando a la API un objeto Funcion con valores predeterminados, les dejo el código de todo lo que se usa:

```
private void btnCrearFuncion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { GrabarFuncion(); }
private async void GrabarFuncion()
{
    fun.IdFuncion = 0;
    fun.IdPeli = Convert.ToInt32(cboPelicula.SelectedValue)+1;
    fun.Peli = cboPelicula.Text;
    fun.FechaHora = dtpFechaHora.Value;
    fun.NroSala = Convert.ToInt32(cboSala.SelectedValue)+1;
    fun.IdFormato = Convert.ToInt32(cboFormato.SelectedValue)+1;
--Acá el objeto funcion "fun" queda con los valores: 
IdPeli= 1, FechaHora= DateTime.Now, NroSala= 1, IdFormato = 1
    if (await GuardarFuncionAsync(fun))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Se grabó con éxito la función... "
                        , "Informe"
                        , MessageBoxButtons.OK
                        , MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        this.Dispose();
    } else
    {

    }
}
private async Task<bool> GuardarFuncionAsync(Funcion fun)
{
    string url = "https://localhost:7088/Funcion";
    string funJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fun);
    var dataJson = await ClienteSingleton.getI().PostAsync(url, funJson);
    if (dataJson.Equals(""))
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ese sería el front, ahora vamos al ClienteSingleton:

```
public class ClienteSingleton
{
    private static ClienteSingleton instance;
    private HttpClient client;
    private ClienteSingleton()
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public static ClienteSingleton getI()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new ClienteSingleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public async Task<string> PostAsync(string urlPost, string dataJson)
{
    StringContent content = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PostAsync(urlPost, content);
    var response = "";
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return response;
}
```

En ese método del clienteSingleton PostAsync, en la parte de la creacion de "content" es que yo digo que está el problema, ya que de ahí pasa a hacer el PostAsync en la API y al llegar, el objeto funcion queda con los valores por defecto, esta es la parte de la API:

```
[HttpPost("/Funcion")]
public IActionResult PostFuncion(Funcion f)
{
    return Ok(app.SaveFuncion(f));

}
```

Ahí, el objeto Funcion "f" ya está con los valores predeterminados de un objeto Funcion nuevo que son:

```
public Funcion()
{
    IdFuncion = IdPeli = NroSala = IdFormato = 0;
    Peli = "";
    FechaHora = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Cabe aclarar que el objeto Funcion está definido en Cine_Back, y lo uso referenciando ese preoyecto (Cine_Back) en el Front (que es donde serializo los valores a JSON como les mostré) y poniendo `Using Cine_back.Entidades` en la parte de arriba de mi código del front (Entidades es la carpeta donde está el objeto Funcion en el back), , pero mi cliente Singleton no tiene ese using.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar estoy acá, ya estuve mucho tiempo con chatGPT y la verdad no sé qué más hacer porque en otra solución está igual el POST y anda de maravilla

Answer (score 2):

lo solucioné, no sé por qué no andaba el StringContent así que busqué otra forma y resulta que se lo puede dar en formatoH HTTP tal que así:

```
string queryString = $"?idFuncion={fun.IdFuncion}&idPeli={fun.IdPeli}&peli={fun.Peli}&fechaHora={fun.FechaHora}&nroSala={fun.NroSala}&idFormato={fun.IdFormato}";
string urlWithQueryString = url + queryString;
var dataJson = await ClienteSingleton.getI().PostAsync(urlWithQueryString);

public async Task<string> PostAsync(string urlPost)
{
    //StringContent content = new StringContent(dataJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage responseHTTP = await client.PostAsync(urlPost, null);
    var response = "";
    if (responseHTTP.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response = await responseHTTP.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes entender es que la información de una solicitud se puede enviar en

1. En el Form
2. En el body (solo para `ApiController`)
3. En la ruta (valor1/valor2/valor3)
4. Query String (?param1=valor1&param2=valor2)
5. En el header

Y el servidor recupera la información en ese mismo orden de relevanciar. Y cuando no está `ApiController` seteado el punto (2) se lo salta

---

Entonces tu problema es que el controller no debe estar seteado como `ApiController`, es decir tu clase debería verse así:

```
namespace CineWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController] //<- Esto te falta
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AlgoController : ControllerBase
    {
```

Y teniendo en cuenta `PostAsync` envía por el `Body` hace que el servidor no lea la información, y es por eso que cuando la envías por `Query String` si te funciona

La solución es por un lado agregar `ApiController`, o establecer en tu `action` el origen de los datos, en tu caso agregando `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost("/Funcion")]
public IActionResult PostFuncion([FromBody]Funcion f)
{
    return Ok(app.SaveFuncion(f));
}
```

---

#### Otras consideraciones

##### Tu controller siempre devuelve status 200

```
public IActionResult PostFuncion(Funcion f)
{
    return Ok(app.SaveFuncion(f));
}
```

Un API debería retornar [códigos HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) adecuados y tu siempre retornas que está todo OK, esto hace que `result.IsSuccessStatusCode` será siempre `True`

```
[HttpPost("/Funcion")]
public IActionResult PostFuncion([FromBody]Funcion f)
{
    //Esto cuando hemos agregado validaciones al modelo
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
    //Tambien podemos retornar la lista de los errores de validación
// return BadRequest(ModelState.Select(a=>a.Value?.Errors.Select(b=>b.ErrorMessage).ToDictionary(k => a.Key, v => v)))

    try
    {
        var result = app.SaveFuncion(f);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500,ex.Message);
    }
}
```

##### PostAsync

Usas `PostAsync`, si estás usando .net +5 puedes usar `PostAsJsonAsync` que convierte el objeto a json automáticamente

##### Tu if se puede mejorar

Esto:

```
if (dataJson.Equals(""))
{
    return true;
} else
{
     return false;
}
```

Se puede escribir como

```
return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataJson);
```